# react-scripts build: Failed to minify the code from this file: opentok.js:1310

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, opentok

I am getting a failed to minify the code error when building my react project using npm run build.

This is code that is causing the error. Can anyone suggest what I could do to fix this?

```
const createLogger = memoize(namespace => {
  /** @type Logger */
  const API = {};

  const setMethods = () => {
    Object.keys(logLevels).forEach(name => {
      const method = logLevels[name].method;
      const log = debug("OpenTok:" + namespace + ":" + name.toLowerCase());
      log.log = console[method].bind(console);
      API[name.toLowerCase()] = log;
    });
  };

  setMethods();
  return API;
});
```

My package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-basic-video-chat",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@opentok/client": "^2.17.0",
    "array.prototype.findindex": "^2.1.0",
    "opentok-react": "^0.10.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.16"
  },
  "homepage": ".",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: One easy way to see what cause the minify problem is to comment everything you think is the problem... try to minify, if it is working uncomment some of the code and try it again and so on until you find the exact lines that cause the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My react-scripts package was out of date. Installing the latest version fixed my problem.